# Can't understand java math class with an else if statement (Code below)

Tags: java, class, math, if-statement

```
public class S1P3 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        int num1 = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
        int num2 = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
        int sign = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()*3));
        int answer;
        System.out.println("\n\n*****");
        if(sign==0)
        {
            System.out.println(num1+" * "+num2);
            answer = num1*num2;
        }
        else if(sign==1)
        {
            System.out.println(num1+" / "+num2);
            answer = num1/num2;
        }
        else if(sign==1)
        {
            System.out.println(num1+" - "+num2);
            answer = num1-num2;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num1+" % "+num2);
            answer = num1%num2;
        }
        System.out.println("*****\n");
        System.out.println("3 ...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("2 ...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("1 ...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("ANSWER: "+answer);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how sign is equal to 2 for two "else ifs". How would the program know which one to choose? Because 2 options are equal to 1 so doesn't that mean that one of them isn't used ? Did the book I use have a typo ? I could use some clarification, thank you !

Comment: _Clarification:_ This is a example of bug. Never do it!

Comment: @PaulVargas and *a example* is an example of a grammatical error ;)

Comment: Excuse me. It burned my server. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5):

That is definitely a **typo**, the third condition (the second `sign==1`) will **never** be reached. It should be `if (sign == 2)` instead.

Comment: ahhh thought so, this had me confused for a while, thank you ! so 0 is for the first choice and 1 is next choice and 2 is next one, however, for ELSE to happen that means that 3 would have to "randomly" be picked correct ? also when I made the variables and set it to *3 does that mean it starts counting like "0 1 2 3" or it goes to "0 1 2" because it counting for 3 numbers ? Because java always starts counting at 0 right ? Sorry for the extra questions thank you !

Comment: Indeed, the final `else` part will only be reached when `sign` equals `3`. Array indices in Java start at 0, but I'm not sure what you mean by "starts counting", could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Small tip: Print out the `sign` variable. That way you can see how it changes.

Comment: I use it as an easy way to follow what is happening to a variable during the run of the application.